# Using root certificate for AWS api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, x509, mutual-authentication

I am trying to use a valid root CA for mutual SSL in AWS api gateway. However, AWS give me this error message: `API Gateway couldn’t build a unique path from the given certificate to a root certificate`.

The certificate is the following:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFgTCCBGmgAwIBAgIQOXJEOvkit1HX02wQ3TE1lTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADB7
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJHQjEbMBkGA1UECAwSR3JlYXRlciBNYW5jaGVzdGVyMRAwDgYD
VQQHDAdTYWxmb3JkMRowGAYDVQQKDBFDb21vZG8gQ0EgTGltaXRlZDEhMB8GA1UE
AwwYQUFBIENlcnRpZmljYXRlIFNlcnZpY2VzMB4XDTE5MDMxMjAwMDAwMFoXDTI4
MTIzMTIzNTk1OVowgYgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpOZXcgSmVyc2V5
MRQwEgYDVQQHEwtKZXJzZXkgQ2l0eTEeMBwGA1UEChMVVGhlIFVTRVJUUlVTVCBO
ZXR3b3JrMS4wLAYDVQQDEyVVU0VSVHJ1c3QgUlNBIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0
aG9yaXR5MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAgBJlFzYOw9sI
s9CsVw127c0n00ytUINh4qogTQktZAnczomfzD2p7PbPwdzx07HWezcoEStH2jnG
vDoZtF+mvX2do2NCtnbyqTsrkfjib9DsFiCQCT7i6HTJGLSR1GJk23+jBvGIGGqQ
Ijy8/hPwhxR79uQfjtTkUcYRZ0YIUcuGFFQ/vDP+fmyc/xadGL1RjjWmp2bIcmfb
IWax1Jt4A8BQOujM8Ny8nkz+rwWWNR9XWrf/zvk9tyy29lTdyOcSOk2uTIq3XJq0
tyA9yn8iNK5+O2hmAUTnAU5GU5szYPeUvlM3kHND8zLDU+/bqv50TmnHa4xgk97E
xwzf4TKuzJM7UXiVZ4vuPVb+DNBpDxsP8yUmazNt925H+nND5X4OpWaxKXwyhGNV
icQNwZNUMBkTrNN9N6frXTpsNVzbQdcS2qlJC9/YgIoJk2KOtWbPJYjNhLixP6Q5
D9kCnusSTJV882sFqV4Wg8y4Z+LoE53MW4LTTLPtW//e5XOsIzstAL81VXQJSdhJ
WBp/kjbmUZIO8yZ9HE0XvMnsQybQv0FfQKlERPSZ51eHnlAfV1SoPv10Yy+xUGUJ
5lhCLkMaTLTwJUdZ+gQek9QmRkpQgbLevni3/GcV4clXhB4PY9bpYrrWX1Uu6lzG
KAgEJTm4Diup8kyXHAc/DVL17e8vgg8CAwEAAaOB8jCB7zAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBSg
EQojPpbxB+zirynvgqV/0DCktDAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUU3m/WqorSs9UgOHYm8Cd8rID
ZsswDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgGGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wEQYDVR0gBAowCDAG
BgRVHSAAMEMGA1UdHwQ8MDowOKA2oDSGMmh0dHA6Ly9jcmwuY29tb2RvY2EuY29t
L0FBQUNlcnRpZmljYXRlU2VydmljZXMuY3JsMDQGCCsGAQUFBwEBBCgwJjAkBggr
BgEFBQcwAYYYaHR0cDovL29jc3AuY29tb2RvY2EuY29tMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBDAUA
A4IBAQAYh1HcdCE9nIrgJ7cz0C7M7PDmy14R3iJvm3WOnnL+5Nb+qh+cli3vA0p+
rvSNb3I8QzvAP+u431yqqcau8vzY7qN7Q/aGNnwU4M309z/+3ri0ivCRlv79Q2R+
/czSAaF9ffgZGclCKxO/WIu6pKJmBHaIkU4MiRTOok3JMrO66BQavHHxW/BBC5gA
CiIDEOUMsfnNkjcZ7Tvx5Dq2+UUTJnWvu6rvP3t3O9LEApE9GQDTF1w52z97GA1F
zZOFli9d31kWTz9RvdVFGD/tSo7oBmF0Ixa1DVBzJ0RHfxBdiSprhTEUxOipakyA
vGp4z7h/jnZymQyd/teRCBaho1+V
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I looked at the content and the CA attribute is set to true. However, the Issuer is different from the subject. Could this explain the AWS error? [image]

[image]

Comment: you cannot use CA certificate directly for authentication, because you don't own it and don't have a private key.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The [aws doc exemple](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-mutual-tls-authentication-for-amazon-api-gateway/) use a root certificate. Also, the private key would be required for signing the request, but the validation should only require the public key (which is in the CA).

Comment: AWS doc uses CA cert to generate and sign client certificate. And client must have a private key in order to use this cert for authentication.

Comment: how did you solve this? I am also getting same issue.

Comment: You need to look at https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/authenticated-origin-pull/set-up/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it including the complete certificate chain.

According to that certificate, I guess that it should work adding the certificate that corresponds with the following serial :

```
            keyid:A0:11:0A:23:3E:96:F1:07:EC:E2:AF:29:EF:82:A5:7F:D0:30:A4:B4
```